# Canceling report run via Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms ReportViewer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it programmatically possible to cancel a long-running report that has been started using the web forms ReportViewer control?  Documentation of `.Reset()` method says

> Call the Reset method to **cancel any current rendering** and reset
>   the ReportViewer control to its default state.

However if I (for example) put a button on the web form to call `reportViewer1.Reset()` on `postback`, the line never actually gets hit until the report is finished.  Viewing `trace.axd`, I can see that the `postback` hangs between `BeginLoadState` and `EndLoadState` until the report finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be calling the report asynchronously in order to cancel it while it is rendering.

Hope this helps,

Bill